# How can I label the points of a quantile-quantile plot composed with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am building a quantile-quantile plot out of an variable called `x` from a data frame called `df` in the working example provided below. I would like to label the points with the `name` variable of my `df` dataset.

Is it possible to do this in ggplot2 without resorting to the painful solution (coding the theoretical distribution by hand and then plotting it against the empirical one)?

**Edit:** it happens that yes, thanks to a user who posted and then deleted his answer. See the comments after Arun's answer below. Thanks to Didzis for his otherwise clever solution with `ggbuild`.

```
# MWE
df <- structure(list(name = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 
10L, 6L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 19L, 18L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
8L, 23L, 11L, 24L), .Label = c("AUS", "AUT", "BEL", "CAN", "CYP", 
"DEU", "DNK", "ESP", "FIN", "FRA", "GBR", "GRC", "IRL", "ITA", 
"JPN", "MLT", "NLD", "NOR", "NZL", "PRT", "SVK", "SVN", "SWE", 
"USA"), class = "factor"), x = c(-0.739390016757746, 0.358177826874146, 
1.10474523846099, -0.250589535389937, -0.423112615445571, -0.862144579740376, 
0.823039669834058, 0.079521521937704, 1.08173649722493, -2.03962942823921, 
1.05571087029737, 0.187147291278723, -0.144770773941437, 0.957990771847331, 
-0.0546549555439176, -2.70142550075757, -0.391588386498849, -0.23855544527369, 
-0.242781575907386, -0.176765072121165, 0.105155860923456, 2.69031085872414, 
-0.158320176671995, -0.564560815972446)), .Names = c("name", 
"x"), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = "data.frame")

library(ggplot2)
qplot(sample = x, data = df) + geom_abline(linetype = "dotted") + theme_bw()

# ... using names instead of points would allow to spot the outliers
```

I am working on an adaptation of [this gist](https://gist.github.com/chrishanretty/3885712), and will consider sending other questions to CrossValidated if I have questions about the regression diagnostics, which might be of interest to CV users.

Comment: someone posted an even direct solution than Didzis and deleted it. It was something like `ggplot(df,aes(sample = x)) + geom_text(label=df$name, stat="qq") + geom_abline(linetype = "dotted")`. In case you're interested.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can save your original QQ plot as object (used function `ggplot()` and `stat_qq()` instead of `qplot()`)

```
g<-ggplot(df, aes(sample = x)) + stat_qq()
```

Then with function `ggplot_build()` you can extract data used for plotting. They are stored in element `data[[1]]`. Saved those data as new data frame.

```
df.new<-ggplot_build(g)$data[[1]]
head(df.new)
           x          y     sample theoretical PANEL group
1 -2.0368341 -2.7014255 -2.7014255  -2.0368341     1     1
2 -1.5341205 -2.0396294 -2.0396294  -1.5341205     1     1
3 -1.2581616 -0.8621446 -0.8621446  -1.2581616     1     1
4 -1.0544725 -0.7393900 -0.7393900  -1.0544725     1     1
5 -0.8871466 -0.5645608 -0.5645608  -0.8871466     1     1
6 -0.7415940 -0.4231126 -0.4231126  -0.7415940     1     1
```

Now you can add to hew data frame names of observations. Important is to use `order()` as data in new data frame are ordered.

```
df.new$name<-df$name[order(df$x)]
```

Now plot new data frame as usual and instead of `geom_point()` provide `geom_text()`.

```
ggplot(df.new,aes(theoretical,sample,label=name))+geom_text()+ 
  geom_abline(linetype = "dotted") + theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) brilliant use of `ggplot_build()`. One question: Where can I read about the lower level control of `ggplot2` like these, any idea??

Comment: @Arun I'm not sure where to find information - I have learned this by looking on other SO questions

Comment: Oh alright, that's nice. I'll keep looking for your answers then! :)

Comment: This should do, thanks! As with the other answer, it involves creating an extra dataset for plotting, but I guess I cannot hope for a better trick.

Answer (score 6):

The points are too close by. I would do something like this:

```
df <- df[with(df, order(x)), ]
df$t <- quantile(rnorm(1000), seq(0, 100, length.out = nrow(df))/100)

p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x=t, y=x)) + geom_point(aes(colour=df$name))
```

This gives:

[image]

If you insist on having labels inside the plot, then, you could try something like:

```
df <- df[with(df, order(x)), ]
df$t <- quantile(rnorm(1000), seq(0, 100, length.out = nrow(df))/100)

p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x=t, y=x)) + geom_point(aes(colour=df$name))
p <- p + geom_text(aes(x=t-0.05, y=x-0.15, label=df$name, size=1, colour=df$name))

p
```

[image]

You can play around with the `x` and `y` coordinates and if you want you can always remove the colour aesthetics.

Comment: +1 Nice rainbow colors :) I think the code for your second plot is missing ?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I thought of that last solution, but would like to do without the creation of additional `rnorm` data just for the plot.

Comment: @Fr., Yes, I don't remember who, but someone posted the direct solution, but unfortunately deleted it. Here's that solution: `ggplot(df,aes(sample = x)) + geom_text(label=df$name, stat="qq") + geom_abline(linetype = "dotted")`

Comment: … you're right, this works, and that's the kind of trick I was looking for in the first place! I'll switch the 'answered' tag to this one, indicating your comment.

Comment: @FR. you can write this as an answer and mark it as such so that this answer doesn't get lost.

Answer (score 0):

@Arun has a good solution in the comment above, but this works with R 4.0.3:

`ggplot(data = df, aes(sample = x)) + geom_qq() + geom_text_repel(label=df$name[order(df$x)], stat="qq") + stat_qq_line()`

Basically the same thing, with addition of `stat_qq_line()` **and `[order(df$x)]` as part of the `label`**. If you don't include the `order` function then your labels will be all out of order and very misleading.

Here's hoping this saves someone else some hours of their life.